# Upload File upload and generate url

Tags: files

I have a site where there are several links to a single file.

Is there a module that allows me to upload a file into the CMS, generate a link and use it as for these links?

The Module would need to keep the same file name if re-uploaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried media module https://www.drupal.org/project/media ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Attachment Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/attachment_links) module. Read the README.txt file for better understating.